# Implementing convolutional layers using Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement convolutional layers for text classification from this [blog post](http://www.wildml.com/2015/12/implementing-a-cnn-for-text-classification-in-tensorflow/) with some modification to suit my needs.

In the blog, there is only one convolution layer while I'd like mine to have two convolutional layers followed by ReLU and max-pooling.

The code so far is:

```
vocab_size = 2000
embedding_size = 100
filter_height = 5
filter_width = embedding_size
no_of_channels = 1
no_of_filters = 256
sequence_length = 50
filter_size = 3
no_of_classes = 26


input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, [None, sequence_length], name="input_x")
input_y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, no_of_classes], name="input_y")



# Defining the embedding layer:

with tf.device('/cpu:0'), tf.name_scope("embedding"):
    W = tf.Variable(tf.random_uniform([vocab_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0), name="W")
    embedded_chars = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(W, input_x)
    embedded_chars_expanded = tf.expand_dims(embedded_chars, -1)


# Convolution block:

with tf.name_scope("convolution-block"):
    filter_shape = [filter_height, embedding_size, no_of_channels, no_of_filters]
    W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(filter_shape, stddev=0.1), name="W")
    b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[no_of_filters]), name="b")

    conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(embedded_chars_expanded,
                   W,
                   strides = [1,1,1,1],
                   padding = "VALID",
                   name = "conv1")

    conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv1,
                    W,
                    strides = [1,1,1,1],
                    padding = "VALID",
                    name = "conv2")
```

Here, W is the filter matrix.

However, this gives the error:

> ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 256 and 1 for 'convolution-block_16/conv2' (op: 'Conv2D') with input shapes: [?,46,1,256], [5,100,1,256].

I realise I have erred in the dimensions of the layer, but I am unable to fix it or put in the correct dimensions.

If anybody could provide any guidance/help, it'd be really helpful.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Can't quite understand what you code to do, but change as follows will fix your problem.

```
with tf.name_scope("convolution-block"):
    filter_shape = [filter_height, embedding_size, no_of_channels, no_of_channels #change the output channel as input#]
    W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal(filter_shape, stddev=0.1), name="W")
    b = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[no_of_filters]), name="b")

    conv1 = tf.nn.conv2d(embedded_chars_expanded,
                   W,
                   strides = [1,1,1,1],
                   padding = "SAME", ##Change the padding scheme
                   name = "conv1")

    conv2 = tf.nn.conv2d(conv1,
                    W,
                    strides = [1,1,1,1],
                    padding = "VALID",
                    name = "conv2")
```